# Are there any solution to make android device as a Cast Receiver?

Tags: android, google-cast

Hello i have an android TV BOX which runs on Android 4.4 
is it possible to make this device as a cast receiver (like chromecast or Android TV)?

Specifically are there any SDK's to write custom app which will run on Android 4.4 as a cast receiver app?

Comment: " is it possible to make this device as a cast receiver (like chromecast or Android TV)?" -- as Mr. Naddaf says, that's not possible. However, some Android apps use Android's built-in `RemotePlaybackClient` to talk to Chromecast, rather than the proprietary Cast SDK. You can create a `MediaRouteProvider` that can serve as a bridge between the apps using `RemotePlaybackClient` and your "android TV BOX".

Comment: @CommonsWare https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.cast.receiver&hl=en

Any idea how this is being done? I think this is a Cast receiver implemented on Mobile. I'd like to replicate this. But it's specific to one sender I think (another app by the same guy).

Comment: @AkasHL: "Any idea how this is being done?" -- well, I would use `RemotePlaybackClient`, talking to my own receiver app via some means (WiFi, WiFi Direct, Bluetooth, lots of tiny carrier pigeons, etc.). "I think this is a Cast receiver implemented on Mobile" -- AFAIK, koush is not implementing the Google Cast protocol.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no such official SDK to do that. Note that the Cast SDK senders check to make sure they are talking to an official Cast receiver.

Comment: Has anything come up after Android 5.1 or later to make android device as cast receiver?

Comment: No, there has been no change there.

Comment: This works as a google cast receiver for android mobile phones. No idea how to do this.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softmedia.receiver.castapp&hl=en_IN

Answer (score 2):

I searched for this for way long, but nothing is really working at the moment.

You can look for cheapcast, an app that would emulate chromecast, but it has been removed from the market due to incompatibility issues...

[Link to the XDA official thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2402387)

Also i heard about a project of a emulator written in python for the raspberry Pi which seemed to work but the project seems stalled since months.
[UPDATE] On the project page the dev wrote he's about to post a new version.

[Link to github of picast](https://github.com/lanceseidman/PiCAST)

Anyway, I can only find documentation on how to produce apps that transmit, but nothing about an open sdk for receiver. It's still closed source.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.cast.receiver&hl=en

Any idea how this is being done? I think this is a Cast receiver implemented on Mobile. I'd like to replicate this.

Comment: Alredy tried that too, but AFAIK it works only with allcast transmitter. It doesn't with Youtube, Play Music, ecc...

Answer (score 0):

For **Sansui** 50 inch **Android smart TV** (android 4.4.2(Kitkat)):

Approach 1:(No Root)

1.Download AirPin/DLNA (Reciever) and sender from official site or use playstore .
Read More :http://www.waxrain.com/product_en.html.

Play Store Link:
1.Reciever
[http://pool.apk.aptoide.com/egbank/com-waxrain-airplaydmr-502-49006891-1dd9a660ae02de8e9cc63b9e5f7a244e.apk],[http://airpin.apk.black/]

2.Sender:[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.waxrain.droidsender]

Approach 2 (Requires Root):

1.Try to root the device .(I Tried with KingRoot worked after 5-6 tries).
used KingRoot. (Kingoroot didn't worked for my tv).

2. Download  File Explorer(Maybe EsFileExplorer/Solid Explorer) 
   {Settings:show Root directory}
3. open root/system/buildProp->

   3.1 Open file in Text Editor.

   3.2 Search for **persist.debug.wfd.enable=0**

   ```
                    {
                      **if found change the value to 1**

                     else/otherwise add : **persist.debug.wfd.enable=1** }
   ```

   3.3 Save the file and restart the system.
4. I used Airscreen apk and installed on  android device on which contents will be casted.
5. Connect to any Wifi and start the service.(Make sure your tv/cast reciever and casting device are on same network.)
   All done you can start connecting if all the steps are completed correctly.

You can explore other apps also for connecting/using miracast service.
(Apps should have minimum-sdk/android version 4.0 or lower to install and run)
Worked for me.Not sure but can give a try.